# Error with Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

Resque was working but now I am getting the following error message: "undefined method `Enqueue' for Resque Client". I haven't changed anything in the code, but now when I look at Resque-Web all my queues are gone. Any idea what could be going on?

Note: If I go on the console I can call the method enqueue on Resque.

Comment: i beleave if you are calling any worker inside any model method you can call the same method from console and at the same time check the resque web if any job is added or not in the queue.

Comment: Please provide a backtrace of the error so that we can help you better